# Where do I find wiki for Karate UI v0.9.4?

Tags: karate

A while ago I used Karate UI to debug Karate tests in IntelliJ. Now the documentation for Karate UI is removed from the wiki, because it is retired from Karate 0.9.5 onwards https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Karate-UI

Where I can find the documentation for Karate UI, if I'm still using v 0.9.4?

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend upgrading and using the Visual Studio Code debugger: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/IDE-Support

Not sure if this is what you wanted, but here is the old page: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Karate-UI/44611bb425556bce4cb83ca4da358c21e7c4f758